# Export a postgis table to geopackage using the database management in QGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis, geopackage

I am working in QGIS through the DB Manager by running some spatial queries. After I create new tables with the queries I need to export the tables as new geopackages.
I've tried using the Export to Vector file inside the DB Manager but I get the following error message:

> Error 2 Creation of data source failed (OGR error:
> sqlite3_open(/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xx/new_geopackage_layer.gpkg)failed:
> unable to open database file)

I've read a couple of posts and they said I needed to create an empty geopackage first and then export the table and save it inside the geopackage but that did not work either. When I try to save inside an existing geopackage
I get an error saying:

> "geopackage.gpkg already exists. Do you want to replace it? A file or
> folder with the same name already exists in the folder xxx Replacing
> it will overwrite its current contents."

If I choose to overwrite then I get a second error message saying:

> " Error 1 Unable to create the datasource.
> /Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/new_geopackage.gpkg exists
> and overwrite flag is false."

All I want is to be able to run spatial queries inside QGIS and be able to export the tables created with the queries as geopackages.

It seems that as of now I won't be able to do this from inside QGIS but instead will need to use ogr2ogr command to export to any file type.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Which Version of qgis are you using?
I tried to export a spatial query from the DB Manager in QGIS 3.26 and it worked flawlessly.

If your version is older maybe try to update it to the newest version first.

Comment: @ffrosch I just downloaded it a month ago with the latest version